# populating data to html table using ajax, jquery and making it searchable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm loading data dynamically to html table as below. I'm using Datatable for ssearch.

Technology stack used is:
Spring MVC
Hibernate
Ajax
JQuery

```
function getdata()
 {
        $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
         url: "/controllerURL.html", //controller URL
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",    

         success: function (results) {
            console.log(results)
             var success = results.success;
            if(success){
            var finaldata = "<tbody><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>data1</th><th>data2</th><th>Update</th></tr></thead>"; //data
            var data = results.message;
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(data);
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    var value = data[i];                
                    finaldata = finaldata+  "<tr><th>"+value.ID+"</th><th>"+value.variable1+"</th><th>"+value.variable2+"</th></tr>";
                                                }
                finaldata = finaldata + "</tbody>";
            $("#tableID").html(finaldata);
             }            
         },
         error: function (data) {       
            alert("fail");
         console.log('ajax call error');    

         }
     });
 }
```

I'm now be able to load data into table. but can someone explain how to add search option to it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "search option".  Are you looking for something like https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Yes.That is what am looking for. It was working with normal HTML table. But, after this AJAX call. search is not working

Comment: what `search` isn't working? Nothing shown here related to searching

Comment: <link href="../../plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
$(function () {
        $("#example1").DataTable(); }

Comment: You should definitely add the fact that you're using datatables to your question.  To update datatables like you're trying to do, when you make an ajax call you have to use the datatables update mechanisms.
https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()
or
https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: Hi Kasdega. var table = $('#tableId').DataTable();
      table.draw();.I've tried redrawing the table after the data got loaded. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datatables [click here](https://www.datatables.net/)

It will provide you various inbuilt functionality that you may want to integrate

```
<!--dependencies for data table -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Your html should look like this

```
 <table id="stable" class="display table-responsive table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Data1</th>
        <th>Data2</th>
        <th>Data3</th>
        <th>Data4</th>
    </tr>

</thead>
```

finally write this script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table').DataTable();
});
```